# How can I change this code from min heap to max heap

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation, min-heap, max-heap

I have the implementation for Dijkstra with min heap, and I tried to change min heap to max heap to find the maximum path, but I could not, the output was wrong 
so, please could you help me to change this implementation to max heap?
many thanks

```
public class DikjstraAlgorithm {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Graph graph = new Graph(9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        graph.addVertex(i);
    }
    graph.addEdge(0, 1, 4);
    graph.addEdge(0, 7, 8);
    graph.addEdge(1, 0, 4);
    graph.addEdge(1, 7, 11);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2, 8);
    graph.addEdge(2, 1, 8);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3, 7);
    graph.addEdge(2, 8, 2);
    graph.addEdge(2, 5, 4);
    graph.addEdge(3, 2, 7);
    graph.addEdge(3, 4, 9);
    graph.addEdge(3, 5, 14);
    graph.addEdge(4, 3, 9);
    graph.addEdge(4, 5, 10);
    graph.addEdge(5, 2, 4);
    graph.addEdge(5, 3, 14);
    graph.addEdge(5, 4, 10);
    graph.addEdge(5, 6, 2);
    graph.addEdge(6, 5, 2);
    graph.addEdge(6, 7, 1);
    graph.addEdge(6, 8, 6);
    graph.addEdge(7, 0, 8);
    graph.addEdge(7, 1, 11);
    graph.addEdge(7, 6, 1);
    graph.addEdge(7, 8, 7);
    graph.addEdge(8, 2, 2);
    graph.addEdge(8, 6, 6);
    graph.addEdge(8, 7, 7);
    graph.findShortestPaths(0);
}

public static class Graph {
    Vertex[] vertices;
    int maxSize;
    int size;

    public Graph(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        vertices = new Vertex[maxSize];
    }

    public void addVertex(int name) {
        vertices[size++] = new Vertex(name);
    }

    public void addEdge(int sourceName, int destinationName, int weight) {
        int srcIndex = sourceName;
        int destiIndex = destinationName;
        vertices[srcIndex].adj = new Neighbour(destiIndex, weight, vertices[srcIndex].adj);
        vertices[destiIndex].indegree++;
    }

    public void findShortestPaths(int sourceName){
        applyDikjstraAlgorith(vertices[sourceName]);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){
            System.out.println("Distance of "+vertices[i].name+" from Source: "+ vertices[i].cost);
        }
    }

    public class Vertex {
        int cost;
        int name;
        Neighbour adj;
        int indegree;
        State state;

        public Vertex(int name) {
            this.name = name;
            cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            state = State.NEW;
        }

        public int compareTo(Vertex v) {
            if (this.cost == v.cost) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (this.cost < v.cost) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public enum State {
        NEW, IN_Q, VISITED
    }

    public class Neighbour {
        int index;
        Neighbour next;
        int weight;

        Neighbour(int index, int weight, Neighbour next) {
            this.index = index;
            this.next = next;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    public void applyDikjstraAlgorith(Vertex src) {
        Heap heap = new Heap(maxSize);
        heap.add(src);
        src.state = State.IN_Q;
        src.cost = 0;
        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = heap.remove();
            u.state = State.VISITED;
            Neighbour temp = u.adj;
            while (temp != null) {
                if (vertices[temp.index].state == State.NEW) {
                    heap.add(vertices[temp.index]);
                    vertices[temp.index].state = State.IN_Q;
                }
                if (vertices[temp.index].cost > u.cost + temp.weight) {
                    vertices[temp.index].cost = u.cost + temp.weight;
                    heap.heapifyUP(vertices[temp.index]);
                }
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Heap {
        private Vertex[] heap;
        private int maxSize;
        private int size;

        public Heap(int maxSize) {
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
            heap = new Vertex[maxSize];
        }

        public void add(Vertex u) {
            heap[size++] = u;
            heapifyUP(size - 1);
        }

        public void heapifyUP(Vertex u) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
                if (u == heap[i]) {
                    heapifyUP(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void heapifyUP(int position) {
            int currentIndex = position;
            Vertex currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
            int parentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) / 2;
            Vertex parentItem = heap[parentIndex];
            while (currentItem.compareTo(parentItem) == -1) {
                swap(currentIndex, parentIndex);
                currentIndex = parentIndex;
                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
                parentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) / 2;
                parentItem = heap[parentIndex];
            }
        }

        public Vertex remove() {
            Vertex v = heap[0];
            swap(0, size - 1);
            heap[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
            heapifyDown(0);
            return v;
        }

        public void heapifyDown(int postion) {
            if (size == 1) {
                return;
            }

            int currentIndex = postion;
            Vertex currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
            int leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
            int rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;
            int childIndex;
            if (heap[leftChildIndex] == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (heap[rightChildIndex] == null) {
                childIndex = leftChildIndex;
            } else if (heap[rightChildIndex].compareTo(heap[leftChildIndex]) == -1) {
                childIndex = rightChildIndex;
            } else {
                childIndex = leftChildIndex;
            }
            Vertex childItem = heap[childIndex];
            while (currentItem.compareTo(childItem) == 1) {
                swap(currentIndex, childIndex);
                currentIndex = childIndex;
                currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
                leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
                rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;
                if (heap[leftChildIndex] == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (heap[rightChildIndex] == null) {
                    childIndex = leftChildIndex;
                } else if (heap[rightChildIndex].compareTo(heap[leftChildIndex]) == -1) {
                    childIndex = rightChildIndex;
                } else {
                    childIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }
            }
        }

        public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
            Vertex temp = heap[index1];
            heap[index1] = heap[index2];
            heap[index2] = temp;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {

            return size == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot just change minheap to maxheap and expect the longest/maximum path as output. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027180/dijkstra-for-longest-path-in-a-dag  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462736/graph-dijkstra-for-the-single-source-longest-path

Answer (score 2):

Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using a maximum heap instead of a minimum heap doesn't result in an algorithm finding the longest path.

In Dijkstra's algorithm, implemented using a minimum heap, it is always true that when a vertex `v` is added, you get the shortest-path distance to `v`. This fact is implied from the observation that the addition of more edges to a path between two vertices cannot make the path any shorter.

However, you don't have an analogous observation in the longest path problem. Even if you fetch from the heap the vertex `v` having the heaviest edge to the set `S` of discovered vertices, the distance from `s` to that vertex could probably be lengthened by adding more edges to the path.

Hence, by implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using a maximum heap, you violate the invariant that all the paths to the discovered vertices are optimal.

Therefore, a variation of Dijksta's algorithm cannot be used to solve the longest path problem. In fact, [the longest path problem is NP-hard](http://www.utdallas.edu/~dzdu/cs6363/unit5.pdf). Hence, under the widely believed complexity assumption that `P` doesn't equal `NP`, you cannot devise a polynomial time algorithm which is guaranteed to find the longest path. Unfortunately, this problem is one of the hardest NP-hard problems in the sense that [the longest path probably cannot even be reasonably approximated](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-27836-8_21).